# Terminal - Macbook GREP query

Tags: grep, terminal, macintosh

I'm successfully using the following terminal command to find specific text in my very large csv file, and creating a separate csv file as ouput:

```
grep "text" filename.csv > outputfile.csv
```

Is there any way I can use a similar command to search for multiple different texts, and save it in the same output file?

Answer (score 2):

You can search for multiple patterns with `-e`:

```
grep -e text1 -e text2 filename.csv > outputfile.csv
```

Tested with GNU grep, FreeBSD grep and busybox grep implementations,
also specified in
[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/grep.html). This
is how `-e` is explained in GNU grep manpage:

```
   -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
          Use PATTERN as the pattern.  If this option is used
          multiple times or is combined with the -f (--file)
          option, search for all patterns given.  This option can
          be used to protect a pattern beginning with "-".
```

Comment: This is the cleanest way imho - especially if the patterns are `"text"`, since it is compatible with the `-F` (`--fixed-strings`) switch

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you could use an "OR"-style alternative in your regular expression:

```
grep "text1\|text2" filename.csv > outputfile.csv
```

or

```
grep -E "text1|text2" filename.csv > outputfile.csv
```

The available syntax will depend somewhat on which version of `grep` you have installed (the above definitely works in GNU grep).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to search for different strings, you can use `egrep` or `grep -E`:

```
egrep "text|string|word|" filename.csv > outputfile.csv

grep -E "seal|walrus|otter" filename.csv > outputfile.csv
```

Those will print out lines containing any of those strings. You can also combine them with other options such as:

```
egrep -v "text|string|word|" filename.csv > outputfile.csv
```

That will print out lines that don't contain any of those strings.